# How do I upvote or downvote comments?

Tags: support, comments, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

How do I upvote or downvote comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can up-vote comments by clicking the up arrow right next to them (you have to hover over the comment to see the arrow).
Down-voting of comments is not possible.

Also: this might be interesting:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755319/how-does-comment-voting-work

Comment: I see that now, after I got some rep points. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a bit of rep to vote on comments too.

you do to vote on questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Specifically, you need 15+ rep to vote on comments (the same as being able to upvote questions and answers).