# Flag a comment as noise/spam

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, comment-flags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What happens after flag a comment as offensive or spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24534/what-happens-after-flag-a-comment-as-offensive-or-spam)
>   [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

I recently flagged a comment in one of SO question as noise/spam... I really dont know what is happening...

- What will happen when one flags a comment as noise/spam?
- How to undo the same?

Comment: (Note the linked duplicate could use a better answer.)

Comment: Actually, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-work covers the information better. It includes the effects that flagging has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it.  The moderators evaluate each comment to determine whether or not it is actually spam before they delete it.

In addition, if enough people flag the comment, it is deleted automatically.  See [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365)

Comment: Not true. If posts or comments collect enough flags, they are auto-deleted without any intervention.