# When should a comment be flagged as "too chatty" vs "off-topic"?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

I was wondering when a comment should be flagged as "too chatty" vs "off-topic"?

I ask because I had the situation where an acquaintance posted the following comment (or something like it) to a question I had edited:

> @Keoki long time no see!

Obviously this comment does nothing to help improve the question or provide an answer, and contributes nothing to the site.  So it seems to me to be "off-topic".  But it also seems to be "chatty".  In this case, does it matter whether I flag the comment using one or the other categorization?  Are they both equally valid?

When would a "too chatty" comment ***not*** also be "off-topic"?

**Update:**
Because I thought it would be useful, I found a post that explains [What are valid reasons for flagging comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/what-are-valid-reasons-for-flagging-comments) in the first place.

Comment: long time no see!

Comment: Okay, what? This question got downvoted...how come?

Comment: A downvote on meta merely indicates disagreement with the topic.  I'd guess, in this case, that someone doesn't think such comments should be flagged at all.  Lots of stuff gets downvoted here, though, and downvotes are nothing to pay particular attention to unless there are more than a few of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When would a "too chatty" comment not also be "off-topic"?

So, fine Stack Overflow users; what's new in the world of programming?

---

It really doesn't matter what you flag the comment as; if it's both, just pick one. I would personally go with "too chatty" in that case