# Do comment flags eventually auto-expire?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, aged-away

It appears that comment flags will never expire?

I think that comment flags should also expire, because if a comment hasn't been flagged 6 times within a given period, it no-longer deemed note-worthy, just like questions and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment flags are now handled by moderators. And since moderators generally process flags within 24 hours, it seems unnecessary to expire those flags.

Back when comment flags were handled by the community, they expired after something like 4 or 6 days (I don't remember exactly), a far longer period of time than it would take the moderators to process them.

Comment: @M.Tibbits: Hmm, maybe. The flagging system was recently given a substantial overhaul to take some of the load off of moderators' backs, and it looks like that FAQ hasn't been updated since that occurred.

Comment: @M.Tibbits: I see you added that comment flags don't expire. I'm not sure that's necessarily true. I didn't state that explicitly in my answer. My point is more that it's irrelevant whether or not they expire, as even the previous expiration period is less than the time it would take them to be processed.

Comment: Makes sense.  In reference to the OP's question, do they auto-expire?  *Should that* be listed in the faq?

Comment: @M.Tibbits: I honestly don't know if they expire anymore. I've never seen one sit in the queue long enough to find out. I don't see how it's relevant, so no, I don't think it should be listed in the FAQ. The point is that comment flags get handled transparently by the moderators. Given the next question the OP asked, it's more likely that he's misunderstanding the way that flags are handled in the first place, and that this is not a particularly germane issue.

Comment: @Cody: From [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/what-are-valid-reasons-for-flagging-comments) I read that most of the comment flagging process works without moderator handling - if a comment gets, e.g., enough "obsolete" flags, then it's just deleted.