# Penalties for being a primadonna on SO and meta

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags

I can't count the number of times that I've seen a post from a well-intended, albeit naive, questioner get the comments section of their post (which can't be down-voted)  hijacked by people who get pleasure from patting each other on the back for being smarter than the questioner. And, on the way out, down-vote the question only because it insults their intelligence.

My questions are these:

- I've never used the flag feature. But, does flagging a comment as unproductive work to deincentivise the user who posts the unproductive message?
- Why should users be limited to only 10 flags? I've seen comment sections long enough to use up most of that allowance.
- If the user has a score of, say, 100K, are they innoculated from anything other than flagrantly disrespectful comments?

Comment: You should concentrate on making better posts instead of hiding behind the fact that you expect downvotes.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by hijacking a question..? You mean editing it?

Comment: What is "the message section of their post (which can't be down-voted)"? And what does "hijacked" mean in this context? These terms are not universally understood by us.

Comment: Do you mean comments?

Comment: @Oded - That's why I posted it as a discussion topic. I can't post an example until I stumble on another one. But, my guess is that most readers can relate to my point.

Comment: You posted this after encountering something - you can't point towards something like that? That kinds suggests that it is rare enough to not really be the problem you seem to think it is.

Comment: @Oded - Yes, the comments section. sometimes the list gets quite long.

Comment: What do you mean by "Why should user's be limited to only 10?" 10 what? Where? When did you encounter this limit?

Comment: He probably means 10 flags (on comments).

Comment: @Oded - when you click the flag button on a SO comment

Comment: @Jeremy Banks - Yes. 10 flags.

Comment: It makes me sad inside that people would upvote a post that is intentionally disrespectful, unclear, and is just obvious flamebait rather than an honest attempt to draw meaningful attention to a problem and with a sincere attempt to have it resolved.  That people encourage this entirely unproductive behavior, ironically enough, is demonstrating the problem that the OP is ranting about.

Comment: @drankin2112: if you see a whole comment thread that has derailed, don't flag each and every comment - flag one, use the "other" option and explain what's going on.

Comment: Note that the number of flags a user has is dependent on their reputation; higher rep users can make more than 10.

Comment: "intentionally disrespectful, unclear, and is just obvious flamebait" - 100% false. @Oded gave a real answer to my questions.

Comment: @drankin2112 That he chose to pretend it wasn't unconstructive and answered it anyway does not mean that it wasn't unconstructive, or disrespectful.  The fact that he didn't understand several of your points and had to edit in answers later means that it was most certainly unclear.  (And the fact that he needs to add qualifications like "Assuming you mean" demonstrates that it's still not very clear.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are valid reasons for flagging comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/what-are-valid-reasons-for-flagging-comments) and of [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits) "You start with 10 flags per day. Based on your reputation and flagging history, you can end up with as many as 100 per day..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I've never used the flag feature. But, does flagging a comment as unproductive work to deincentivise the user who posts the unproductive message?

Flagging comments as unproductive puts them in the moderator queue. If a moderator agrees with the sentiment, the comment will be removed. Users with a long history of nonconstructive comments may receive a warning or even be suspended.

> Why should user's be limited to only 10? I've seen comment sections long enough to use up most of that allowance.

Assuming you mean the limit on the number of flags - consider that **every single user** can flag comments. There is no need for more, assuming a comment is truly rude/offensive - these are handled by moderators. Piling on flags on the comments that are on a single post will not make a difference. As you earn reputation on the site and demonstrate the ability to use your flags properly, [you'll be given more each day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890).

> If the user has a score of, say 100K, are they inoculated from anything other than flagrantly disrespectful comments?

We have a rule - "be nice". If you see a comment that is rude or offensive, flag it as such. Having high reputation means nothing in this regard and we have had high reputation users suspended because of such behavior.

Comment: Thank you for asking clarifying questions and then answering them directly. I didn't expect such a quick and impassioned response from everyone. There are prima donnas on SO and I really just wanted clarity behind the flagging rules on SE sites. Thanks again. You win.

Comment: And then Oded makes a rude or offensive remark, but isn't banned, not only because he's a moderator, but high rep ;)

Comment: Watch it @Cole.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't count the number of times that I've seen a post from a well-intended, albeit naive, questioner get the comments section of their post (which can't be down-voted) hijacked by people who get pleasure from patting each other on the back for being smarter than the questioner. And, on the way out, down-vote the question only because it insults their intelligence.

I can't count the number of times a user came here with the same unclear request about how the community has been mean to them in the comment section.

Let's get something straight, Well-Intended is not what makes a post valid for the website. We all get our first post downvoted badly or get a bad reception when we start here because there are rules that we must follow in order to get a proper collection of good questions and answers running. When this happens you have two choices, learn to fit in and read the help center to ask better posts and improve with the time in order to help other users. Or be against the whole thing, come here on meta, thinking of being the first one to post a non well received question by the community and whine about it thinking the whole system will change.

If all the users took the time to read the help center and the guidelines before posting, we wouldn't  be having this discussion.

Now as for the questions which are btw kind of unclear.

> I've never used the flag feature. But, does flagging a comment as unproductive work to deincentivise the user who posts the unproductive message?

I'm no Stack Exchange developer but I'm pretty sure collecting flags like you would collect the hats is not a good thing. A flag collector will, one day, hit a wall. (get banned)

> Why should user's be limited to only 10? I've seen comment sections long enough to use up most of that allowance.

10 flags limit? It's to limit flag abuses. We don't want to fill up the flag review queue with users that are unhappy with the reception of their bad "code this for me plz" posts and that decided to flag every comments below.

> If the user has a score of, say, 100K, are they innoculated from anything other than flagrantly disrespectful comments?

I'm sorry but I don't even understand that question.

Comment: "I'm no Stack Exchange developer but I'm pretty sure collecting flags like you would collect the hats is not a good thing."  You get bronze, silver and gold badges for it, and the number of "helpful flags" appears on your profile. Key word, "helpful." So, this is wrong.

Comment: @djechlin Wow. You got the whole thing around. A flag collector in this example is someone that has his own posts flagged a lot. Key word : The question I'm answering ?

Comment: I see. Yeah I'd clarify that in your post.