# Upvoting comments doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, up-votes, meta

When I try to upvote a comment, nothing happens when I click on the arrow. If I click on it again, the red "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds." error appears, yet the comment vote is not there.

Reloading the page shows that the upvote wasn't indeed acquired.

---

### Summary update to address all comments:

- Yes, I was happily voting comments one hour ago.
- Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7 x64.
- Tried waiting, reloading page, restarting IE, logging out and in again.
- This only happens on Meta.

It ***could*** be a vote limit problem (I casted some today, can't remember how many exactly, though); but, was this the case, shouldn't an error message appear instead of the vote just plainly disappearing?

---

### Update:

Thanks for troubleshooting this, followed up in [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53957/no-error-message-when-out-of-comment-votes-the-vote-is-simply-ignored).

Comment: Have you cast any comment votes today, prior to this issue?

Comment: may be clean some cache on browser, wait another 5 seconds, and try again upvoting?

Comment: @ccomet: yes, two hours ago it worked fine.

Comment: @S.Mark, tried that, closed and re-opened the browser, all the basic troubleshoot steps.

Comment: Curiosity... have you perhaps cast *a lot* of comment votes today? Also, while I'm inquiring, browser/OS? And is this behavior only on Meta, or on all sites?

Comment: @massimo, on any comments? I am not sure there is upvote comments limit per day though.

Comment: @S.Mark [30 votes per day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-work/17365#17365).

Comment: @ccomet, oh ok, I am seeing lots of comments on his "Why was Apocalyptic Defense closed?!?" thread, may be he used all the votes.

Comment: @S.Mark That's what I'm suspecting, that the limit is inexplicably invisible.

Comment: I think I've only hit the limit twice (once was the day they were introduced), but I'm pretty sure I saw a popup notification that I'd hit my limit.

Comment: I just tried to use all my comment votes on that post, and I got *"Daily vote limit reached; come back in 7 hours."* message. *FF3.6.3Win32*

Comment: @S.Mark Pwa, that means the 20 votes I just spent on SO are instead wasted! ...except they aren't in vain. I have stumbled across something...

Comment: @ccomet, it wasn't waste at all, you could reproduced it, while I can't.

Comment: @S.Mark That comment was prior to replicating the behavior. It took 20 votes before I started to see this behavior. However, that's because I changed my pattern at around 20 votes in, so I can't conclude between whether the vote volume caused the behavior change at some point or if the behavior was present from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very strange bug with where the popup error message divs should be attached to. IE8 somehow wasn't keeping a reference to a jQuery object when inside an ajax callback closure.  No other browsers had a problem, not even IE8 running in compatibility mode (i.e. IE7).

The fix was to send a string jQuery selector telling where to attach the popup message div.

Answer (score 4):

You are indeed out of votes. I have reproduced this on IE8 on XP. I did not receive an error for running out of votes, but I picked a place with exactly 31 comments so it was easy to tell.

I noted two things during this. The first time I would try to make an illegal vote (within 5 seconds), I wouldn't get a pop up. In fact, as long as I never clicked the same comment again within a certain 5 second window, I could continually make failed comment votes. Eventually the 5 second window would finish and my vote would get through.

Amidst all of this, I did run out of votes. Unlike what mmyers and S.Mark indicate, I did not actually receive a message for the "Daily vote limit reached". But I've spent 30 votes and now if I try to upvote any comment, it will behave exactly as Massimo explains: it flashes, does not submit the vote, and a second attempt brings up the 5 second pop up.

Comment: Yes, I had to click upvote and wait 5 seconds, and click vpvote again to get "Daily vote limit reached; come back in 7 hours." in IE8, clicking within 5 seconds give me "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds." error.