# No error message when out of comment votes, the vote is simply ignored

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, up-votes

A follow-up to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53875/upvoting-comments-doesnt-work).

When out of daily comment votes and trying to upvote a comment, no error message appears; the act of clicking on the up arrow left of the comment is simply ignored.

If I click again before 5 seconds have passed, I get the error "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds", but still nothing about being out of votes.

This happens (to me) using Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Upvoting comments doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53875/upvoting-comments-doesnt-work/53996#53996)