# What happens to *comments* when flagged?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, offensive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does comment voting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-work)

I've been searching meta but can only find posts about flagging questions and answers... What happens to comments when they're flagged offensive?

And another question - is a user notified if his comment has been flagged?

Comment: See the [relevant FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-work/17365#17365) for all details on flagging comments.

Comment: @Grace Note - can you provide a link? I was only able to find info about flagging posts. Are comments treated the same way?

Comment: The words "relevant FAQ" are a link. Also, to answer your secondary question, no, there is no report, just like with comment upvotes.

Comment: Flagged comments burn in a very special level of hell. A level they reserve for child molesters, and people who talk at the theater.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: shiny!