# numbers next to comments?

Tags: support, comments

What do they mean?

here's an example, if you expand the comments there is a '1' next to one of them...

[Java reading JSON null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294829/java-reading-json-null/3294891#3294891)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it has 1 [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work); you can vote on comments by hovering the mouse on the left of them.

Comment: Try it on this one

Comment: ah -- do you get reputation for that?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: No, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work.

Comment: Comment upvote whoring!!! =P

Comment: @devinb, I already have [everything](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit?user_id=1782) I can get from that :)