# How does comment sort order work?

Tags: support, comments

Hope, the question is clear from the title itself.

1. How does comment sort order work?
2. Is there any difference in comment sort order for question and answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sorted by date, unless you use a greasemonkey script, e.g. [for threaded comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43055/greasemonkey-script-for-displaying-threaded-comments). If there are many comments, some (those with the least great-comment votes) may be hidden by default, however.

Comment: As for hidden comments, see [this old revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17365/8) of "How does comment voting and flagging work?"