# Why upvote a comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

I'm curious as to why comment upvotes are a feature, if they are not worth any reputation ( I thought at one point they were worth one). I know not everything should be done for reputation but sometimes I see a comment I like and I upvote it however the person posting it gets nothing from that upvote (or probably even any indication that it has been upvoted).

I *did* search MSO and gave up after two pages from this search string (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+upvote+comment).

Edit: in fact sometimes a comment in an answer or a question is more helpful than any of the provided answers.

Comment: That question and accepted answer don't answer the commentator not getting anything out of it portion of the question (ironically a comment sheds some light on it but it is someone's opinion, not sure if it's based on fact).

Comment: @Duncan the duplicate is added on top of the question itself. Personally I disagree this is a duplicate so I voted to reopen, but I'm only one person.

Comment: I don't believe I have the rep to vote to reopen, but I agree with @ShaWizDowArd that the possible duplicate is not the same question and I could not find the answer to this question in that question's answers. The other question is more with the mechanics and with the 'why' of flagging commenting, not the why of upvoting commenting (which I think the answers here better answer).

Comment: @ajacian81 see the bullet point on comment badges in the voting faq duplicate, that's virtually the only benefit other than prestige.

Answer (score 6):

Why? Because it help others to determine "here, this is a good comment".

Also, you are wrong - having 10 comments with score of 5 or more grants the [Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit) badge and this is really neat and shiny badge to have. :)

Comment: Badges, we got to collect them all...

Answer (score 5):

If a post has many comments, not all will be displayed.

*The sort of the comments is based on score when their count exceeds the count of visible comments.*

This makes sure that trivial comments don't hide important ones. And if a post has many comments it "highlights" the really good ones.

Comment: Not accurate. The sort of the comments is based on score when their count exceeds the count of visible comments. All will be displayed when clicking the "see all" link.

Comment: But it doesn't help the original commentator. I've seen comments with hundreds or 60+ "scores" and it seems weird that they get nothing (or little) from that.  I think it would encourage people to post comments more than full blown answers.

Comment: It helps the original commenter with a "pat on the back". But the real help is meant for others viewing the conversation...

Comment: Hi ajacian81, actually, we really don't want people to post comments just for the sake of posting them. Comments are really just intended to help clarify questions or suggest improvements to answers. Many times, important information from comments are placed inside the question and answer bodies, and the comments themselves are deleted by moderators or community flags.

Comment: I feel upvoting @ShaWizDowArd's comment is not (all) what *you* should have done, juergen. Since you agree, shouldn't you have edited your answer instead/too? (See also: [How does comment sort order work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63061/how-does-comment-sort-order-work))