# Order of comments changes when expanding comments

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Recently I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121111/css-selected-tag-higher-than-class). The second answer has more than 5 comments so comments can be expanded. If I do so, the order of comments changes. This does not seem to make sense. Correct me if a system is behind this behaviour.

Comment: [How do comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) explains the sorting and exclusion of lower-voted comments from the compact view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.

Comments with positive score will appear first, as it usually means "those are good comments".

Also, see this: [How does comment sort order work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63061/how-does-comment-sort-order-work)

Comment: I respect the design decision, but the concept does not feel very intuitive. Normal users will have problems understanding the idea, I think.

Comment: Might be so, in my opinion it's a good thing but I'm not normal user, lol. You can start new post here on Meta tagged feature-request asking to change this behavior but I don't think you will have much luck..

Answer (score 6):

It is not the *order* of comments that changes. Some comments are excluded from the compact view and included in the full view. But the order remains the same.