# Why didn't I receive any reputation from my upvoted comment?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

A comment made by me on 2010-09-28 20:01:56Z on the question [How can I safely average two unsigned ints in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816446/how-can-i-safely-average-two-unsigned-ints-in-c) received some upvotes. But, I think, they did get not included in my reputation. Is that possible? Is there any kind of log that I can check out?

Comment: No, but there is a known/expected lack of background information in this question.

Comment: BTW, since you asked about a log, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you have provided some background and a link, it is obvious that you are referring to a *comment* of yours rather than an *answer*.

While you do get reputation for upvotes on your answers (and questions), upvotes on your comments *do not gain you any rep, ever*. As Grace Note mentioned, there is a [comment voting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365), where it is expressly stated that:

> - No reputation of any kind is earned or lost from comment votes, though the [Pundit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit) badge is awarded to those who left 10 comments with score of 10 or more.