# Have I been permanently banned from suggesting edits

Tags: support, edit-ban

I was unable to suggest edits to questions on Stack Overflow. But now I see after a long time I am still unable. I thought it would be fixed after some time.

I don't know why that happened. Almost all of my edits are accepted. And also I have improved them. So, why am I restricted from that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why didn't I receive any reputation from my upvoted comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66071/why-didnt-i-receive-any-reputation-from-my-upvoted-comment)

Comment: @muru It's just a part. Not whole. Okay??

Comment: And that's why we don't like multiple unrelated questions being asked in a single post.

Comment: Which site? SO? or MSE?

Comment: @SurajRao StackOverFliw

Comment: shouldnt this be asked in MSO then? or did you find anything to make you think the issue is network wide?

Comment: [As of now, you have 30 edit suggestions approved, and 14 edit suggestions rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9181423/aa-shakil?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) in Stack Overflow

Comment: @arulkumar So, can't I suggest anymore?

Comment: are you getting any message when you suggest?

Comment: _"Almost all of my edits are accepted"_ - Not sure that 30 approved to 14 rejected is considered "almost all."

Comment: @SurajRao User can't suggest edits to this question. I'm using SE App.

Comment: can you _please_ provide all _relevant info_ about your issue? are you able to do it in website but not in app?

Comment: Closing as unclear what you ask because what you said is totally wrong, and you didn't bother to give any useful details. For example, what message you see when you try to suggest edits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moderators should be able to manually ban users from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)

Comment: Many more of them should have been rejected in my view. Your [most recent effort](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18592635) almost was, only the inexperienced OP accepted, and it's definitely not an improvement (the formatting is totally unnecessary and you broke the grammar of the title). Given the negative feedback on your own formatting, maybe don't apply it to others' posts? I'd strongly recommend you spend a bit more time *lurking* on these communities to understand how they operate, as your current headlong approach doesn't seem to be working out.

Comment: It’s StackOverflow not StackOverFliw (second time in the last day I have seen StackOverFliw being used)

Comment: As S.L. Barth indicates, I personally banned you from suggesting edits for a week (the duration should have been shown to you when you tried to suggest more). We had received complaints about your edits, and in reviewing several of them I found them to introduce superfluous formatting, add unnecessary wording, and in one or two cases even make posts grammatically incorrect. Many of these edits ignored other problems. I manually rejected several of these that had already been approved, to show you ones I thought to be problematic. Please take the time to review what was wrong with them.

Answer (score 8):

Some of your edits on Stack Overflow have been overruled by a diamond moderator. It is very well possible that he gave you an edit ban. The edits added noise and applied markdown where it was not needed. **IF** the moderator manually banned you from editing, that is probably the reason.

An edit ban is temporary, but the duration varies. You might get a warning when you try to suggest an edit, telling you when you can suggest edits again.

Meanwhile, I suggest you learn more about markdown. You were already explained that block quotes are only for quotes. Yet in this question you used block quotes again for emphasis.

If you do not want to get edit banned again, then learn when to use markdown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think stackoverflow is so disillusioned. I like discipline though it's tough.

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, Stack Overflow is hard!

Comment: Hey Barth could you please give me some links from where I can learn full about markdown.

Comment: I've tried to get all editing information together [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/812149) on MSO. A few rules of thumb: quote markdown is only for quotes. `code markdown` is only for code. Personally, I also believe that **boldface** and _italics_ should be avoided when possible.