# do flagged comments destroy user reputation?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Every few days I see comment-threads between two users trying to contact each other over skype or AIM or gmail. I've been flagging them because I see it as *noise*, but I'm feeling guilty if the flagged comments generate [-100 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) for the poster. (Especially since most of those users are new, and fairly low-rep. 100 points is a lot when you're new.)

So: Do flagged *comments* generate (the same? any?) negative reputation as flagged *posts*?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)—in short, no

Comment: Excellent @waiwai933, thanks. (I'd like to suggest my post be closed, it's got an easy answer, but left as a signpost to the future; I didn't find that post when searching.)

Comment: @waiwai933: The answer in that post says that there's no penalty *yet*, but that "yet" was put in 2 years ago. It's hard to know if it's current.