# Discourage 'google for it' answers

Tags: feature-request, google

Although there are posts relating to 'just google it' answers, which seem to look on it as bad style (maybe 70/30), I haven't found a specific feature request.

I'd like to see a feature that pops up a message discouraging direct links to search engines.

I'm not suggesting blocking links to google, because there may well be valid times for doing this, for example if someone is showing a problem query, or illustrating styles for google results.

Similarly, I don't think it would be practical to screen on google as a keyword, as there are many legitimate uses (names of Google products and services).

The more technical arguments about 'google it answers' being bad are:

1. These answers get top ranking in search results, hiding real answers
2. Searching is easier when you know the answer (and hence the keywords)
3. Search results change over time (and location), so what works for the answerer may not work for the reader (or later readers)
4. Sites listed in answers go away, or lose ranking. While the dead-site issue is also a problem for direct links, SO could purge dead links, but not dead searches.

Feedback welcome

Comment: @YOU I didn't find that in my searches for previous posts, however feature #2 is the more important. I'll think on this and edit appropriately.

Comment: The primary mechanism for discouraging such answers is crushing them under a hail of downvotes. If you have any current examples I'd be happy to sacrifice a few rep to the effort.

Comment: I don't have current examples, as it doesn't annoy me enough to keep track of. However, I think I normally see this in comments rather than answers, so downvoting isn't an option (and bad style isn't a reason to flag for a mod)

Comment: @Phil: [Flagging a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/2509) is different from [flagging for moderator attention](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/). Feel free to do it when you think a comment is out of line.

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think this is a duplicate of the lmgtfy article - I edited the lmgtfy part of the post a full hour before it was closed as duplicate (or the duplicate comment was inserted). Additionally, I'm specifically suggesting a feature to discourage (not prevent) certain styles of answer - the suggested duplicate is a discussion of style, not a proposal for a middle-ground solution

Comment: @Phil the question was re-opened.

Comment: can you provide specific examples of the types of posts you are referring to? I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean without concrete examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree **strongly** with limiting the ability to paste Google links into
 comments in any way. 
There is a category of brain-dead, exceedingly trivial questions, that can be answered by a link to the proper, authoritative page in the respective manual ("How do I replace a string in PHP?"). In those cases - and only those! - informing the OP of the existence of search engines is perfectly okay in my eyes.

Sometimes, it is right to comment "Just Google it" and a (polite) RTFM in the form of a manual link. Not always, mind, and it's always good to err on the lenient side. But sometimes, it really is.

*Answers* consisting of just a Google link or a mere RTFM are not okay, for the reasons you state. But as @dmckee points out,  those are usually downvoted into the ground anyway.

[Current example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696263/php-convert-date-to-certain-format) where the user should have searched SO

Comment: Wouldn't the trivial questions all have duplicates by now?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting blocking the ability, just that a popup should appear, along the lines of 'Are you sure?' Perhaps I wasn't clear that I expected the poster to still be able to say 'Yes, I want to do this'.

Comment: I disagree with "RTFM" ever being an answer. It's fine as a comment, but as an answer it should include some useful information, like a link to the documentation page that includes the answer (that is to say, *not* a link to the documentation's TOC).

Comment: @Gabe I didn't mean to defend RTFM *answers*, just comments. I fixed the wording

Comment: @Phil but to what end? Truly offensive comments can be flagged. Everything else is fair game in comments IMO.

Comment: The problem, asking really basic questions, already has a solution: closure. Tons of dumb questions by systemic problem users has a solution too: bans on asking questions. RTFM/LMGTFY is just a crass and anachronistic throwback to when lording over newbies was considered cool. Everyone was a newbie once, and everyone asks really dumb questions once in a while: RTFM/Google links don't change that, and they add no value to an answer or a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the most useful answers to my questions have been links to Google search results.

Often knowing what something is called and knowing the terms to search for is 90% of the problem.

Comment: That might be true, but ask yourself a question: How often have you found on your searches through the web the suggestion to search it on the web? Personally, I'm sick of seeing that. We're here to provide answers, not clues or breadcrumbs.

Comment: @Bobby when I have a problem, I want it solved.  It it helps other people great, but a **quick** clues or breadcrumbs is often worth more to me then a "full" answers that comes later.   However the voting system will get the full answer to the top, so other people an find it.