# What will happen after I flag a comment as each reason?

Tags: support, flags

The flag comment reasons as follows:

[image]

In [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work), I noticed this rule:

"*If a comment is flagged by enough users it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it.*"

According to my experience, It seems that the rule of comments flag is not similar to questions and answers flag. Question will be auto-soft-deleted only when it flaged as offensive or spamming.

What will happen after I flag a comment as each reason?

Does the comment will be auto-soft-deleted no matter users choose any reasons?

Does Stack Overflow will inform moderator after user flag a comment no matter he/she choose any reasons?

Comment: How do you flag a comment as "every reason?"  That option doesn't appear to be in the list.

Comment: Your account will be placed in an auto-triggered timeout that prevents you from asking questions for a day.

Comment: @random will be here all week.  Badaboom.

Comment: I think the OP means "what happens for each of the flag reasons."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderators see all comment flags regardless of reason, and yes, I believe the soft deletes do occur regardless of the reason selected.  You can only flag a comment once.