# Comment flags for smaller sites should appear as other flags do, atop each page

Tags: feature-request, notifications, moderator-tools, comment-flags

I request that smaller Stack Exchange sites' mods get notification of comment flags atop each page, where notification of post flags is. Rationale:

- Smaller sites don't have as many comment flags, so mods won't be bombarded by flags. So the "too many flags, so no notification" reason doesn't apply.
- Likewise, mods on smaller sites don't have many post-flag notifications atop the page, to which the comment-flag notifications are adding noise.
- Mods on smaller sites don't check the /admin/dashboard as often, as there are few post flags; thus, they're likely to miss comment flags without the notification. (Moreover, if comment flags appear atop each page, then they don't *need* to check /admin/dashboard, so optimal behavior will match current behavior. `:-)` )
- The benefit is of course that they can check the flagged comment for deletion; smaller sites also have fewer users, so the comment is less likely to be [deleted automatically (by having several people flag it)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17365) without mod attention.

What's a "smaller site"? Perhaps any in (private or public) beta. But actually I think it should be one that doesn't have many post flags:

- Once a site has many post flags, mods will check /admin/dashboard periodically anyway, so don't need comment-flag notification atop each page.
- Once a site has many post flags, the comment-flag notification atop each page will be noise with respect to the signal of post-flag notification.
- If a site has many post flags, people are obviously flagging, so comment flags will accumulate also, and comments will be deleted without needing mod attention.

Okay, but what does "many post flags" mean? What's "many"? That I don't know; maybe one a day? Please offer suggestions in answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does seem a bit inconsistent, so we plan to address this; and indeed, a comment can be just as offensive (or just as innocuous) as any other type of flagged content. Hence (re yoda's reply) I'm not sure it is *entirely* valid to just say "ignore them", but as a compromise, I've broken down the posts vs comments count in the title text for the counter:

[image]

(which is from my local fake environment, so ignore the numbers!)

Comment: Will it light up for a single comment flag too (if no other mod flags)? Could it be done such that only `rude/offensive` and `other` comment flags are shown in the counter for immediate moderator attention? The `too chatty` and `obsolete` comments can be done at a slower pace (besides Community raises a mod flag anyway for >20 flags). However, I'm not too hell bent on it, and if you say no, that's fine. But please do consider :)

Comment: @yoda it seems a bit arbitrary to single out those ones...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't want this feature. My first inclination when I see a red bulb light up anywhere on the SE screen is to click it. Comments are second class citizens and comment flags are even lower on the totem pole. Those flags are mostly from users asking the mods to clean up clutter. This can be done at a leisurely pace when I happen to visit the dashboard and I do not wish to be bothered by it ever so often.

Processing comment flags should be like blowing leaves away from the driveway in fall - just drop by in the evening or every other day and blow them away en masse. What you're suggesting is the equivalent of being alerted every time a leaf falls and having to rush to it with a blower. That is pure insanity.

If theres a comment that needs immediate attention, well, that's most likely a spam/offensive comment and 6 community flags should get rid of it automatically. If the community doesn't manage to garner 6 flags for a truly offensive post, then there's a bigger problem lurking...

If the comment has sensitive/private information, then they should flag the post to bring it to the moderator's attention.

Comment: Please reread the question. I'm referring specifically to smaller sites, where the community is unlikely to flag an offensive comment six times, and where mods don't have post flags that they need to visit the dashboard for.

Comment: I read your question fine. I moderate two sites that are smaller than yours and still would not like to be bothered by comment flags. It's more a matter of principle and respect for _my_ time, than if it's a major inconvenience or not.

Comment: I must say that I only visit the dashboard when there are flags at all ... and on Crypto, we get a quite small number of post flags. (It says 22 the last 30 days, but I only see 10 in the details table.) I don't know how often a comment flag happens (I have never seen one), but when it happens, I want to know this not only two days later. Maybe some differentiation between offensive/spam and the less urgent flag types might be in order here?

Comment: does the compromise (in my reply) suffice, @yoda?