# Can you delete comments from my question if I have a good reason?

Tags: support, comments, specific-question

I opened [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646166/analyzing-a-rubik-cube-using-aforge-net) and i received a few comments which now are meaningless.

I didn't explain my question very well and now i hope it's understandable.

Can you delete the other users' comments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A moderator can clean up old, obsolete or rude comments for you; simply flag the comments which you think should be removed, or flag your question if the entire comment thread consists of e-drama. Posting on meta, while valid, is often less effective; the mod queue is the best way to get to us for help.

Anyway, I've cleaned up the comments for you. I still think one of them applies though:

> What have you tried so far?

Consider adding even more information. For example, you state that you've tried the CannyEdgeDetector; how have you tried it? Perhaps including some code that you've written will better facilitate our helping you with your problem, as it'll give us a starting point to work with.

Comment: Also see [How do comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) and [When should comments be deleted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/when-should-comments-be-deleted)