# How comes some of my comments have been silently removed?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

I just figured that some of my comments on an answer to the question [power of in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680303/power-of-in-assembly/12682713) have been removed without further notice...

Is that common practice on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Depends on what your comments were.

Comment: don't you have a look at some history? I'm afraid this question would be deleted as well if I'm repeating my words (they were not abusive, but kinda harsh). But they led the other discussionist to finally give credit where credit was due, so they can't have been all that wrong...

Comment: You mean where you were being rude/offensive?  [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice)

Comment: @casperOne: did you read the thread?

Comment: @JaggedO'Neill Doesn't matter, other people's actions are no excuse for rudeness on Stack Overflow.  If you think that another person's comments were rude or offensive, flag the comment, *do not* be rude/offensive in return.

Answer (score 19):

Looks like your comments were removed because they were flagged as '`rude/offensive`' and a moderator agreed with the flag.

Looking at them, I would have deleted them too.

Comments are removed for a myriad of reasons:

- Obsolete
- Rude/Offensive
- Not Constructive
- Chatty
- It's Tuesday
- Spam

The point is, Comments are meant to clarify posts, not to hold extended discussions, not to argue, and not to throw temper tantrums.  If you want something with permanence, make it an answer (providing it is actually an answer).

So to answer your question: Yes, deleting comments that fit the criteria above is common practice.

Comment: I wonder what day of the week really is most risky for arbitrary comment deletion.

Comment: @Yar to paraphrase Twain, Thursday, Tuesday, Monday. Other days are Sunday, Saturday, Wednesday and Friday.

Answer (score 14):

Comments can be flagged by community users as such:

[image]

If the flags reach a certain threshold, then the comment will indeed be silently removed. Moderators can however still see them (and the flags).

Try posting more constructive comments, or just accept that once your comment becomes obsolete, it'll be deleted. The community is just trying to keep everything clean and constructive.

#### See also:

- [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Comment: okay, i guess you're a moderator or something like that... could you do me a favor and check for such flags? I didn't see any (else I wouldn't have said "without notice". Thanks in advance...

Comment: @JaggedO'Neill There's a list of mods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/about#moderators). Including [George Stocker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149170/145982)

Comment: No, I am not a moderator.

Comment: @JaggedO'Neill You don't get notified if one of your comments (or questions or answers) is flagged for moderator attention.

Answer (score -7):

I am sorry that I can't accept both of the answers, but I gratefully upvoted both. I think/hope this makes up for the -2 I've earned for the question.

Still, I'm not yet satisfied, so I'm asking for one more favor: I wasn't able to delete all my posts... And since you seem to be (which leaves the slight impression of some alien-controlled self-determination (not to use such rude words like "censorship" or "dictatorship")), I'm kindly asking you to remove any content that is under my copyright, i. e. all the contributions I made, be they questions, answers and (please, also any) comments (that I might have overlooked).

I'm sure, since you obviously prefer plagiarism (even though it "only" was a light form of that) over original contributions — at the expense of honest and knowledge sharing contributors — you don't need me anyway... there will be plenty of people out there yearning for those little numbers that you call reputation... just show me one little contribution that I made, that was not of quality and faculty.

Oh, of course, you will mention these comments now. Just as casperOne said, "other people's actions are no excuse for rudeness", just me giving them no reason is excuse enough? — seriously, casperOne, when someone is trying to grab some of your goods on the street, do you ask him "Please wait, I need to call a moderator..."? — And really, just because we're not on open streets (though I vaguely remember the term *information highway*), does this mean, everyone can take everything from me? What about the netiquette? Ain't I still a human being, even if at "the other end"?

And then I can ask again: Who was the first being *obsolete* (just for you to figure: the solution existed already), *rude/offensive* (by taking what was not their's ¹), *not constructive*??? Was it me? The *not constructive* you can have... as I said: just play DCE (delete/close/erase)... oh, and then you can assign my "reputation" to nrz of course... if it yearns for it so much :-)

And BTW: the only constructive contribution to this thread (except my very own question and answer, indeed ;-) was the one of Anna... reminds me of Bad Religion somehow (no offense against you, Anna! I really liked your comment... it displays part of "behind the scenes" (don't wanna repeat my assumptions from above)).

And since I'm still the bad guy: Go, study Schopenhauer... :-)

Have fun... and don't forget to play DCE!

¹ And let me repeat: Exactly these comments finally made him admit that the answer was there already... and from whom.

Comment: oh, -5 already :-)

Comment: Votes on meta are different... they can mean simple disagreement with a question/proposal

Comment: and you think i care about something like soc reputation? -- what about my request to remove my account?

Comment: @JaggedO'Neill If you want your content disassociated from your user ID and your UserID deleted, please send an email to `team@stackoverflow.com` or flag one of your answers and explain that.  Your content won't be deleted because it's under the [CC license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: This is a really constructive response, by the way.  "You guys are mean meanies so I'm going to ragequit and delete all my content because I disagree" isn't the most mature way to handle a disagreement.  It lends some credence to the idea that your comments were validly deleted if this is indicative of your other interactions on the site.

Comment: For the record, there was no plagiarism here at all. A user independently arrived at a similar solution to you, using different code, and you proceeded to accuse him of copying you and insulting him with "self-important arrogant guys like you" and "Makes me think you're a simple para...dingsbums." That's unacceptable behavior anywhere, which is why I removed those comments of yours. I do take claims of plagiarism very seriously, but that's not what happened here. In fact, this user went as far as giving you credit for suggesting a given solution first after you initially pointed this out.

Comment: and he used instructions that were completely unnecessary for "his" solution... he would never have come across these instructions (in this context) if he had independently developed his code... -- anyway, calling it plagiarism or not, I actually posted the code for that other ppl could benefit from it (I still think that's what this site is actually for), just the way _how_ he used it was what made me upset. But if nobody attaches the least value to this, I am certainly at the wrong place.