# What does it mean for a comment to be "auto-soft-deleted"?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

[How do comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/145982) says:

> If a comment is flagged by enough users it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it.

What does "auto-soft-delete" mean?

Answer (score 5):

"Auto" as in it happens automatically, a moderator doesn't need to get involved. "Soft" because it's not actually gone from the database; moderators can still see it if necessary. It's not quite as "soft" as post deletion, because comments can't be undeleted, but the contents are at least recoverable if necessary