# I want to report inappropriate remarks made in comment and in the chat by the user

Tags: support, comments, chat, flags

I came across a user who posted inappropriate remarks to the answer provided by me.

Below is the link to the chat. I feel that the comments are inappropriate and anybody who knows hindi language should feel the same.

[how custom listview search i do not pass array list to custom listview class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964859/how-custom-listview-search-i-do-not-pass-array-list-to-custom-listview-class/15965006#comment22865408_15965006)

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28284/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-raghunandan.

So i would like to know the way i can report the same to bring moderators attention.

Comment: Flag them and be done with it. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work

Comment: @ bart i would like to know how to do the same. Use the flag option below the question?

Comment: Or on the comments themselves. See the link I've added to my comment above. Don't comment back. Don't try to discuss it. Just flag and walk away.

Comment: @bart thanks for the link. I followed the steps.

Comment: @Raghunandan now that user has removed by magic mode left click ..... thanks to mod

Comment: @NullPointer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177502/should-the-post-be-flagged-as-inappropriate-if-the-answer-posted-does-not-attemp. thats because the answer made by user was also offensive and rude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to situations like this is always to flag. [Flag the offensive comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) as "rude or offensive". And that's it.

Similarly, if the comments are specifically made in chat, you can also flag those.

After that, just walk away. Don't comment back. Don't try to reasons with someone leaving offensive comments. It's pointless. Just let moderators deal with it if there is a need to do so.

Should you find that your comment flags have little effect over an extended period of time, then you could perhaps go for a more extensive flag, i.e. the "other" option, and provide a custom explanation of what is going on. But give the situation some time to resolve itself before you do so.

Comment: you mentioned about little effect for extended period. Should that be few days? Like 2-3 days? then flag the question with the exaplanation

Comment: @Raghunandan I would give that a day at least, yes. And only in a really serious case. If the user continues for example. Other than that, I usually assume the moderators are handling the situation as they see fit.

Comment: Being a native Hindi speaker I can understand those comment and Those comment are literally offensive abusive  I would rather want to see that user either suspend or deleted for that

Comment: @NullPointer Flag and explain.

Comment: @Bart i am really dont know how to explain in flag those are related to sex and gender related abuse/Expletive

Comment: @NullPointer You just did. It doesn't have to be a full explanation. Just flag and say that the content is very offensive and what the general gist is. Then moderators can see what they do. If they can't confirm it at that moment, they will at least have something on the record if more such flags come up.