# Should the post be flagged as inappropriate if the answer posted does not attempt to answer the question?

Tags: support

In the link below one of the users posted an answer. Collected a bounty for the same.

[how custom listview search i do not pass array list to custom listview class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964859/how-custom-listview-search-i-do-not-pass-array-list-to-custom-listview-class/16141077#16141077)

The below quote is from the answer in the link

> nobody give its right answer of this question, and it is wastage of
>   our points with others.. f**k

Is this not inappropriate. The user accepts the answer. The answer posted does not attempt to answer the question. (probably uses inappropriate words).

I had flagged a comment posted by the person who asked the question on the same post. It was removed by the moderators.

So should i flag the answer in this case?

Comment: This is totally "not an answer"

Comment: @HugoDozois so should i flag the answer as inappropriate. Is the words used in the answer not offensive or rude?

Comment: You could flag it as inappropriate, but I think the best thing here is to flag it with a custom flag, explaining the situation a bit.

Comment: This looks a lot like a *suck-puppet* case, where he asked his friend to post on the question and gave him the bounty instead of putting it on any other answer.

Comment: @HugoDozois ok i understand. Is the words used not rude or offensive in this case?

Comment: Answer deleted.

Comment: I find it amusing how they're  talking about "our points". @RobertHarvey maybe you could check if there's some other reputation shenanigans going on?

Comment: Yeah, that's weird that they both use the phrase `nobody give its right answer`.  Aaaaaaand suspended.

Comment: @slhck: There is another (deleted) answer there that says basically the same exact thing from a second user, who is actually the user who awarded that +50 bounty to the one that just got deleted. Gee...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer deleted.

Flags are appropriate on these kinds of answers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the support.