# How can we know who raised a flag on our question/answer posted in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, flags

Do we have any certain reputation number to see who raised flag on our questions/answers posted in Stack Overflow?

*Or*

Are those flags only visible to the moderators?

Comment: All flags are private. Only mods can see who raised the flag.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Who reviews my flags and suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203216/who-reviews-my-flags-and-suggestions), https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269666/how-are-flags-handled, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176791/what-happens-when-questions-answers-comments-are-flagged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would it matter who raised a flag on your post? The flag is either valid or it's not.

- If it's not then nothing happens to your post or to your account.
- If it is then it's your post that's the cause of the problem. There has to be something significantly wrong with it i.e. it's spam or abusive or misuses the answer facility to ask another question.

But yes, only moderators can see flags because they are the ones we've empowered to handle the processing of flags.

Answer (score 4):

Flags and reputation have nothing to do with each other. [Reputation unlocks the flagging privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), but you don't get reputation for every X flags raised.

However, a public count is visible of your helpful flags. For example, this is yours on this site at the moment:

[image: Impact Jacqueline]

You can find this page by looking at your user-profile (under Activity) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1215053/jacqueline?tab=topactivity).

More detailed information (who flagged which post) is only available to moderators and the team (CMs and developers). This is not a privilege you can unlock any other way.

People voting to close your question become visible when the question is closed, in the blue banner above it. Not the flaggers, if there were any (doesn't have to be if the first to encounter the question has [close-vote privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)).

Comment: ('topactivity' is *Activity* → *Summary* (the default for *Activity*).)