# How are flagged comments handled?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Who reviews flagged comments? Is that a community vote process, or is it done by individual moderators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flagged comments are reviewed by diamond moderators. A certain number of flags can automatically delete the comment, without moderator intervention; I'm not sure if that's only true for *rude/offensive* flags, or any kind of flag.

For more details, see [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)