# Flagging users who post useless comments

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

One of the things I find really annoying about Stack Overflow is that many users will post useless comments and others will upvote them. If someone doesn't think you did do your homework, then they have the right to flag a post as such, but they should not be allowed to post poor comments.

There should be a "flag as unconstructive" next to comments (and not just solutions posted). If some people are constantly in the habit of posting useless comments, penalties should be taken like locking them out of Stack Overflow for a few days. Then maybe they would think twice about making such comments. Just have a look at the comments on this post for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358769/reduce-this-code-to-a-simple-function-call

People on Stack Overflow shouldn't be able to get away with this. If they don't like a post, they should either ignore it or flag it under some category.

Comment: There is such a flag.

Comment: You can **already** flag comments as not constructive.

Comment: Err, what comments do you have a problem with there? The one that asks you what you've tried? The one automatically generated when someone voted to close the question as off-topic? The one that proposes a solution?

Comment: And to lock someone out of Stack Overflow as a penalty? That is *overly* harsh. Not to mention that none of the comments on the post you linked to even warrant being flagged.

Comment: Rule #1: Extra downvotes will be awarded for those who complain about previous justified downvotes

Comment: Rule #2: Extra downvotes will be awarded because it is Wednesday. Or Tuesday. Or some other day that ends in -Day.

Answer (score 10):

You can already do this.

[image]

Just hover over the area to the left of the comment and click "flag."

However, none of the comments there really deserve to be flagged (see the bottom of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/180276)). You should *always* research your problem and post what you have tried in your questions. Please read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

As Doorknob points out, there already is a mechanism for flagging rude or unconstructive comments. In fact, a couple of comments on that question were indeed flagged and deleted by a moderator:

> I found a lot of dorks posting comments like Neal.

and

> How shocking that there are so many arrogant people like you who waste time posting comments!

These were both insulting to others, and were removed as a result. The user responsible was warned about this, which is our standard procedure. If there is a more persistent issue, or if the comments were very far over the line, we can temporarily suspend an account to give someone a little time to cool off.

I'm guessing you probably wouldn't have wanted for the system to automatically suspend the account of the person behind those comments in response to these flags.