# Dealing with unhelpful users & encouraging more helpful comments

Tags: discussion, comments

A few times lately I've encountered users who are, in my opinion, not using comments responsibly enough. Mainly all they do is leave comments literally like

```
read some tutorial  
this answer has mistakes  
fix your grammar
```

etc. I feel like if everyone will just leave a comment like this to every question/answer, there'll be lots of useless garbage around. Not only that, but it is actually not helpful at all, and this is what we are doing here (trying to be helpful). It would be fine to say/do along the lines of:

```
Please read introductory tutorial about blah-blah (link). 
You have a mistake in your code - I believe you need to blah-blah-blah
(don't say anything, just fix a couple of grammar mistakes in the question)
```

What can I do to deal with it? I don't want to go to all of those comments and reply and offend (or even provoke) the person(s). Also I don't feel like I have the authority to dictate anything to him/her. At the same time, noting something like this on just one comment will hardly alter the behavioral pattern.

Comment: All you can do is provide good comments yourself and flag inappropriate ones.

Comment: Flag such comments as 'not constructive' or 'offensive/rude'.

Comment: @jurgen-d Well, I can't add anything to comment like "your answer is bad" because I might not know and be curious to know why it is bad. It undermines the answer not making any effort to prove that it is wrong or improve it.

Comment: So flag it as not constructive like Aziz says. Or post `@` comment asking simply "why do you think that?".

Comment: I do flag such comments as non-constructive. Users that accumulate too many such flags on their comments may end up with some attention from a moderator. You could also (in a friendly way) tell them there are more constructive ways of saying what they are saying. There is also the [code of conduct in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) you can link to.

Comment: Words cannot express how powerful the urge to edit the first block into Americanized haiku is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the users are otherwise good contributors, we can't do *too much* to prevent these comments from appearing.

- You can `@` reply to them and kindly suggest that they elaborate more in their comments (proceed with care - many people, especially those making such comments, are likely take offence from even the kindest of attempts).

  You can also point them to [a script that allows you to store a few comments and insert them with a click of a button](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).
- You can add a better comment and hope they're still around to see it and perhaps get inspired to follow your example.
- You can check their comments (under `activity` on their user profile) to see whether they give an *excessive* amount of these comments - if so, you can probably flag one and explain your concern and a moderator can decide if any action needs to be taken.

  This may lead to a formal warning, a ban or revoked commenting privileges (most likely just if they're essentially spamming these comments, they aren't otherwise decent contributors or the comments are extremely bad).

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange (or any other similar site for that matter) does not operate to change someones behavior. However, Stack Exchange has provided guidelines and tools to keep this site cleaner and friendlier, such as:

1. Lead by example. Don't provoke others by telling them that their comments are inappropriate. Simply, add a better comment.
2. Flag inappropriate comments as 'Not Constructive' or 'Rude/Offensive'. There are mechanisms in place which could [automatically remove such comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365) when flagged.

On the other hand, users may have their own reasons to leave such comments:

- They maybe in a hurry and dont have time to write a detailed comment
- They got tired of writing detailed comments because they may have faced too many bad posts
- They don't feel that what they are writing could be rude to someone else

Comment: "They got tired of writing detailed comments" - [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) helps (although not always as many comments should be more specific).

Comment: To the last three points: neither of those are a valid reason to leave a useless comment. If you don't have time - don't comment; the fact that there are other bad posts doesn't make this particular OP aware of them; I don't say it is rude - I say it is irresponsible, rude comments should be flagged by default.

Comment: @sashkello I agree with you and I also don't think they are valid reasons but it is subjective. We can't force other users to change their way of thinking. I believe that what we think as a "useless" comment, there could be many users who would disagree with us. Majority of SO users do want to seek help and provide help, very few (if there are any) would like to offend/ridicule help seekers.