# What does the number near a comment mean?

Tags: discussion

Sorry but I'm a new user and I couldn't find anything about this here. Can anybody tell me what does it mean.

Here I don't see any arrow:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the number of times someone "voted up" your comment.  See [How do comment voting and flagging work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) for more information.

You need 15 reputation to upvote comments.