# Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I view a lot of comments every day.

Like this:

> Brilliant. Cheers, Christian, your solution is perfect. –  Mike J Oct 29 '12 at 19:06
>
> @MikeJ Glad to help! –  CB. Oct 29 '12 at 19:07
>
> do you mind if I ask you one more question? I'm hoping to fix the same issue for the 'logFile' and 'attributes' fields. Is there a way I can write the same sort of 'join' statement with the ';'? I tried using the same format you provided but substituting attributes for bindings but had no luck. –  Mike J Oct 29 '12 at 19:24
>
> Thanks again! I don't have enough of a reputation to +1 as I just joined, but your solution was perfect again. Thank you kindly. –  Mike J Oct 29 '12 at 19:41
>
> @MikeJ Never mind... always happy to help! –  CB. Oct 29 '12 at 19:44

I often run across comments with 'Hi' and 'Thanks', etc. on comments.

Should these items be removed by an editor?

Source: 
*[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)*

Comment: It's a comment, which is considered second class, I'm not sure it'd be worth the trouble of trying to remove it from the text.

Comment: Note that no one but developers and moderators can edit comments; the original author can only edit the comment in the first 5 minutes. So your only option is: deletion. Flag such comments as 'too chatty' and a moderator will clean them up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Moderators can edit comments.

Comment: @bluefeet: ah, wasn't aware of that. Still, we are not going to make moderators into comment editors.

Comment: We are all-powerful. You should know that by now @MartijnPieters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Developer should be delete comment ?

Comment: @bluefeet: then why won't you grant me my three wishes? All I ask for is a mansion, a yacht and the fortune to keep both!

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I could do that, I'd grant my own wishes.

Answer (score 13):

No, for comments of the type you quote the whole comment should be removed.

Things like this are just noise and don't add anything to the question or answer.

Simply flag the comment as "too chatty" and a moderator will come along and delete it, if it hasn't already been deleted by enough users flagging it:

> - If a comment is flagged by enough users it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it.
>
> [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365)

Comment: @Kiquenet: I am still not sure, what you are asking, but I give it a try: The amount of flags you can make per day is displayed at the bottom of the dialogue for flagging comments. Unless you make a lot of disputed (i.e., not useful) flags or abuse this feature in another way, there is no penalty to be expected. (Also not that when you say you are a developer in this context, this implies that you work for Stack Exchange. Whether you are a developer in general does not matter.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Great. For a SO user like me, how many flags can I set without get downvotes neither penalty for me ?

Great explain. Abuse, what's number of flags per day ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: Please carefully read the [FAQ on flagging comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/255554)