# Can users see their own comment upvote number somewhere?

Tags: support, comments, voting

The FAQ *[How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/172266)* contains the question *And can users see their own comment upvote number somewhere?*.  However, [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/172266) does not cover this.

Can users see their own comment upvote number somewhere?

Comment: I've updated the FAQ to include the answer to your question.  Please [take a look.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/276629#276629)

Comment: Note that the `My Comments (sorted by score)` script in the link provided above does not work.