# Warn me for trying to flag comments I've already flagged

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, flags, comment-flags

[image]

When I rollover the place where the "Upvote" and "Flag" buttons should be on a comment I've flagged, I get just the little flag icon. Fine, but clicking it does nothing, and is just confusing -- I have to wonder about why I can't flag or upvote this comment.

Perhaps a red "You cannot flag a comment more than once" or "You have already flagged this comment" dialogue, or just a tooltip when I hover the flag icon with one of the aforementioned texts.

Comment: Maybe add a tooltip when you hover over it, but don't get rid of that flag icon – it's helpful to show when flagging multiple comments in the same chain.