# Are "trigger keywords" matched in mentioned usernames as well?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, flags

I have read [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/824803)

> Comments containing certain "trigger" keywords are deleted instantly after a single flag, regardless of upvotes. The list of trigger keywords is kept secret, and may differ per site.

Let's say a person's username contains these trigger words as a substring. For example, Ak**shit**, Dik**shit**, and others. These are typical Indian names, I am sure there would be similar examples from other countries as well. Hope you got the idea! Considering the "s" word in bold is a triggered word.

**If I mention them in comments and someone flags it, are these mentioned usernames also matched?**

For example:

> @dikshit some comment blah blah blah

Disclaimer: My intentions are not derogatory here. I don't mean to disrespect anyone having the names as in the above examples. Apologies for any coincidence.

Comment: In this case, I would probably classify this as a bug (CC @Glorfindel) - This behaviour isn't fair with such users, is completely unintended and can be abused.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems so; I've just flagged such a comment [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/203982/18673) as No Longer Needed with my sockpuppet and it was instantly deleted. I see no reason why it should be, other than that the username contains a dirty word.

[image]

To clarify:

- M. Afrashteh is the author of the comment (and of the question); their username doesn't play any role here
- @KshitijSingh is mentioned in the comment, and their username contains the 'dirty word' (and they're the author of the answer)
- My sockpuppet, a regular user with 101 reputation flagged the comment, that's why the screenshot says 'deleted by'. This information is only visible to ♦ moderators.

When you visit the answer, you'll notice other comments have been deleted as well, because they were no longer necessary.

Comment: OK, but the mod who did delete the comment, did so because the flag used was "no longer needed" not because the username was offensive. Maybe there were other flags? Does that mean anyone can flag a comment for being offensive and that gets instantly zapped.

Comment: *Maybe there were other flags? Does that mean anyone can flag a comment for being offensive and that gets instantly zapped.*, exactly, if the trigger keywords is somewhere in the comment, regardless of how it's used. No moderator touched that comment.

Comment: There is a Greek recipe called [*pas**tits**io*](https://www.taste.com.au/recipes/pastitso-2/cc816921-20fd-4ec0-b04a-691ee159e889) would a user citing that dish, even if perfectly on-topic, find their comment deleted if got flagged? I'm not convinced a user with a perfectly inoffensive name risks having their comments deleted by the system because it is too stupid to realize that the username is innocent.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Its the Scunthrope Effect. (Try flagging this :D )

Comment: @JourneymanGeek As a fan of lower-division football in the UK, I would often read match reports on the library computers, which would render the name as "S horpe". We still refer to the team as S horpe to this day...

Answer (score 7):

"Trigger words" is inaccurate; there is a regular expression that, if matched, will allow 1-flag deletion.

That expression does contain words, and some are included in such a way as to match if that word is matched anywhere within a comment's text - even in a name...

...**However.** It is a complicated expression, or at least it was as if the start of this year; I doubt it has been simplified, nor should it be. Most of the patterns matched by it require more than a simple string of characters; in fact, some depend on the length of the entire comment! More commonly, words are required to be delimited by a non-word character of some sort, greatly reducing the likelihood of [clbuttic mistakes](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-).

Comment: //ignore classic, scunthrope and that town in england ...

Comment: I would like to know if it's true that a comment flagged, where the username is @KshitijSingh, would automatically be deleted as suggested in Glorfindel's answer. And if that were not the case, then what other reason could there be for a comment be immediately deleted by the system. Thanks.

Comment: Entirely possible that "shit" is part of the expression without boundary checks, @Mari-LouA. The original expression was something like 7 dirty words separated by |, and I assume that list remains in some form.

Comment: So an Indian or any person whose legitimate and inoffensive name happens to contain a vulgar expression, a [joey word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/is-there-a-term-for-a-word-inside-another-word/105124#105124), risks seeing their comments deleted because one user knows they can flag the comments and see them magically disappear. The system is, therefore,  flawed.

Comment: No, they risk seeing comments *addressed to them* deleted, @Mari-LouA. The check isn't run on the author's name, but on the text of the comment itself. Also likely to affect discussions of shitsu dogs on [pets.se] and Wankel engines on [mechanics.se]. Someone should probably sit down, do some analysis and refine the expression...

Comment: "Also likely to affect discussions of shitsu dogs on Pets" - not if you use the correct spelling, which is "shih tzu".

Comment: LOL... Got me there, @F1Krazy